# Why do dividend reinvestments not match my calculator?

Tags: ira, calculation, dividends, dividend-reinvestment

I've seen this occur numerous times in my IRAs.  In the transaction section of my Fidelity IRA, it shows a line item `Reinvestment XXX` with a dollar amount.  Clicking the details will display the reinvested shares and the price.

However the amount Fidelity shows does not match what I compute using my calculator.

A specific example:

```
10/01/2015 REINVESTMENT ISHARES CORE S&P SMALL-CAP ETF (IJR) (Cash)
     Symbol IJR
     Description    ISHARES CORE S&P SMALL-CAP ETF
     Shares + 0.298
     Price  106.0916
     Amount -$31.59
```

When I do `Start>Run>Calc.exe`

```
.298 * 106.0916 = 31.6152968
```

As negligible as it is - where does the other .025xx cents go?  Is it an implied fee to Fidelity?  If so, why is it not reasonably disclosed?  Could it just be a rounding issue?

I know it's only two cents - but it's two cents per quarter for-almost-ever and my OCD doesn't like the numbers to not match.

A similar transaction can be noted in Vanguard - so it's not just Fidelity.   My wife's 403(b) invests $200 per paycheck (monthly) - and the Vanguard `transaction history` shows:

```
10/23/2015  500 Index Fund Inv  Buy 1.044   $191.64 $200.00
```

Again, by my calculator - 1.044 * 191.64  = $200.07216

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably a rounding discrepancy.  Try doing the math the other way around:

```
31.59 / 106.0916 = 0.297761556...
```

. . . which rounds to 0.298.  Likewise for your other example, `200 / 191.64 = 1.043623436`, which rounds to 1.044.

In general I would take the dollar amount as the starting point, because the divided is paid in dollars.  You get $X from the dividend and then you see how many shares you can buy; you don't see the share price and decide to buy 0.298 shares and then figure out how much that costs.